# Extracting vectors along 3-D array in opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, multidimensional-array, 3d

Is there an efficient  way (i.e., without copying data) in **openCV** to create vector along the third dimension of a 3D Mat, like in MATLAB:

```
X=rand(3,4,5);

V=squeeze(X(2,2,:));% vector along the third dimension of elements in second row and col.
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you declare your Mat? In OpenCV, a Mat is a 2D matrix with (possibly) multiple channels. Something like `CV_8UC3`, in which case the value at a given position `(m,n)` is a vector of 3 elements.

Comment: I declare it as 3D double array with `int Sizes[]={100,20,35}; Mat MyMat(3,Sizes,CV_64FC1)` , its actually taken as a one-channel Mat.

Comment: Wow, I've never done that, though I certainly see the `ndims` parameter in the constructor now that I look. Very interesting.

Comment: Benny K, did you find a way to do this?

Comment: Well, if the sizes of the 3D array are `const int sizes[] = {3,4,5};` and the original Mat is `Mat M1(3,sizes,CV_8UC1);` then `int Row = 2, Col = 2; // zero - based`
....
`Mat M2(sizes[2],1,CV_8UC1,M1.data+sizes[2]*(Col+sizes[1]*Row));`
should do the trick